# Recovering BTRFS, btrfsck fails; what next?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

### Update

I wound up giving up on repairing the FS, and instead got a new pair of HDDs, created a new BTRFS pool, and used rsync to transfer data from the remaining good disk.

### Server setup

- Rockstor, latest stable (can't check exact version right now)
- 3 hard drives: OS drive + 2 "Storage" drives
- Storage drives are BTRFS RAID 1, `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`
- btrfs-progs v4.12

### Initial problem

- Properly shut down the computer last night, everything seemed fine

  - Ironically, to protect the filesystem during a thunderstorm
- Start up again, everything seems fine and working
- Attempt to run a backup to a share on it, keep getting permission denied
- All subvolumes are mounted properly except `MyVol`
- I/O error when attempting to enter this directory

### Investigation so far

- SMART checks I'd run one or two days ago returned with no errors
- dmesg shows this error (note that the "found" is higher than "wanted"):

  - `BTRFS error (device sdb): parent transid verify failed on 5293051445248 wanted 1522252 found 1526184`
- Power off, physically disconnect `/dev/sdb`, power on, mount the drive in degraded mode:

  - `$ mount -t btrfs -o ro,recovery,degraded /dev/sdb /mnt` (Note: /dev/sdc is now /dev/sdb)
  - Same result as before: Everything else mounts, but can't access `/mnt/MyVol`, same transid errors.
- Able to recover data from recent snapshot (`/mnt/.shapshots/MyVol/MyVol-monthly_date`)
- Run `btrfsck /dev/sdb`, it fails while checking extents

  - Same error when using superblock 1 or 2

```
warning, device 1 is missing
Checking filesystem on /dev/sdb
UUID: 5b1726e8-eb11-46de-b974-f3ca3cb3a41d
checking extents
// Takes a few minutes, then fails:
cmds-check.c:5494: check_owner_ref: BUG_ON `rec->is_root` triggered, value 1
btrfs check[0x454958]
btrfs check[0x40bd93]
btrfs check[0x45bfa6]
btrfs check[0x45c1ea]
btrfs check[0x45cf99]
btrfs check(cmd_check+0x935)[0x4605f5]
btrfs check(main+0x80)[0x4122c0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f205c58b505]
btrfs check[0x4123cd]
Aborted
```

- Following [this answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/407766/89465), I ran `btrfs rescue zero-log`, which failed with:

```
warning, device 1 is missing
Clearing log on /dev/sdb, previous log_root 0, level 0

// Waits a couple of minutes then fails:

Unable to find block group for 0
extent-tree.c:287: find_search_start: Warning: assertion `1` failed, value 1
btrfs-zero-log(btrfs_reserve_extent+0x713)[0x4198b3]
btrfs-zero-log(btrfs_alloc_free_block+0x6a)[0x419e2a]
btrfs-zero-log(__btrfs_cow_block+0x199)[0x409e39]
btrfs-zero-log(btrfs_cow_block+0x111)[0x40a651]
btrfs-zero-log[0x4101b8]
btrfs-zero-log(btrfs_commit_transaction+0x97)[0x4120d7]
btrfs-zero-log(main+0x180)[0x4089b0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7faaec3c7505]
btrfs-zero-log[0x408ac5]

// Above error repeats another 2 times

Aborted
```

- Attempted to use `btrfs rescue super-recover -v /dev/sdb`, all superblocks are marked as good.
- Ran `btrfsck --subvol-extents $MyVol_volid /dev/sdb`, completely successfully after ~15 minutes

  - Prints same transid error, followed by ignoring transid
  - I don't know how to interpret the `Root` or `Roots` columns, but it doesn't look notable
- I've been searching for these errors, and reading through many posts on many forums, and haven't been able to find anything to explain them, or a definitive approach to resolve the issue.

### Potential next steps

One of:

- `btrfsck --repair`
- `btrfsck --init-extent-tree`
- Delete the offending subvolume (if I can)
- Wipe the drive, copy data back over

  - I'm saving this until all other options have been eliminated.

However, both of these are flagged as dangerous, and could break things even further. I'm waiting until I can rsync to another hard drive before attempting `--repair`

### My questions

1. What could be the actual problem with the filesystem?

- The transid points to journal issues, but the zero-log and other errors make me skeptical.

2. What tools/commands have I missed to figure out what's wrong?
3. What are the next step(s) I should take?

Comment: `parent transid verify failed` errors are nearly always fatal to the filesystem. It's always best to write on the BTRFS mailing list when you have issues, as those folks know the filesystem inside-out and can probably suggest ways of recovering your data. Also read the wiki: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page